# In Java JDK 1.6 I need to run an executable that takes in redirected input

Tags: java, executable, runtime.exec, processbuilder, java-6

In Java JDK 1.6 I need to run an executable that takes in redirected input, like so:

```
exe < input_file
```

My code looks like this:

```
final ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder( "exe", "<", "input_file");

// Set working directory
pb.directory( new File( hps.hdfFilePath ) );

// Execute
p = pb.start( );
```

This results in error: "File < not found"

ProcessBuilder does not like the "<". How do I do this in JDK 1.6?

Comment: You can use the various `redirectXStream` methods to leverage this.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis you can, but not with JDK 1.6 as per the question.

Answer (score 2):

Redirection is performed by the shell, so you need to launch the shell. Currently, you are launching your executable and passing it two arguments, '<' and 'input_file'.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html for the documentation of ProcessBuilder.

It is important to note that everythin after the first parameter of the constructor is interpreted as an command line argument.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("exe");
Process p = pb.start();
OutputStream pos = p.getOutputStream();

InputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File("input_file"));
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int read = 0;
while((read = input.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    pos.write(buffer, 0, read);
}
input.close();
```